# [A]How to use setFullScreen methode in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have a stage with these properties

```
stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
stage.setFullScreen(true);
stage.setFullScreenExitHint("");
stage.setTitle("My App");
stage.getIcons().add(new Image(icon-address));
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setController(this);
...
...//and other properties
```

It is in `full screen` in this stage. I have a `button` and each time I click on it , a method of another class is called and the reference of this stage is passed to it.

For example, if I have two classes `Start` and `ButtonClicked`

In Start, I have this :

```
Button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

     @Override
     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          buttonClicked a = new buttonClicked ();
          try {
             a.render(stage);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(menuController.class.getName())
                                              .log(Level.SEVERE, null , ex);
          }
     }
});
```

Now, the render method is called and I have the following code inside render  :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("buttonclicked.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.setController(this);//set Controller for our fxml file
loader = fxmlLoader.load();//loader is a stackPane because buttonclick.fxml has stackPane
stage.setScene(new Scene(loader));
stage.setFullScreen(true);
...
```

The problem is, if user clicks on button, stage become a 1024x700(because i have pictures in start.fxml and buttonclicked.fxml. The size of both the picture is `1024x700`

After a moment, it becomes full screen. How can i fix this ?

I want to kill the delay in full screen

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try stage.getScene().setRoot(loader); in the render method?

Comment: thanks it works ! 
can you explain why should i use this for kill the delay ?

Comment: By doing this, the creation of new scene is eliminated. Therefore I guess, some UI related updates and calculations that must be done after the scene has been shown, are also eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
stage.getScene().setRoot(loader);
```

in render method.
By doing this, the creation of a new scene is eliminated. Therefore I guess, some UI related updates and calculations that must be done after the scene has been shown, are also eliminated.